# Falling Object Rebound

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, collision, free-fall

Can someone please explain to me how to calculate the rebound velocity, rebound acceleration, and rebound height of an object of mass=m dropped from height=h? Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the coefficient of restitution of the ground and ball ?

Comment: Can you please add more details and what you've tried?

Comment: @quirkyturtle98 - I've tried ALOT of googling but most information is related to before impact or at impact and not much is out there about the post impact dynamics

Comment: @ Tausif Hossain - Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, I dont know the coefficient of restitution.  Any good sources that you can recommend or ways to determine it empirically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to calculate the rebound velocity and rebound height you need to know something called the *coefficient of restitution* which tells you how elastic/ inelastic the collision between the ground and object is.

The coefficient of restitution,$e$ is:
$$e=\frac{v_(rebound)}{v_(impact)}$$
Thus if you know $e$ then you can find rebound velocity.( Notice if collision is perfectly elastic then e=1 and rebound velocity = impact velocity and rebound height= original height)

For rebound height just use $v^2=u^2+2gh$ to find $h_(after-rebound)$ setting $v=0$ and $u=v_(rebound)$.
Now to find the acceleration you need to know the collision *time* between object and ground.
Then acceleration,$a$ is simply given by :
$$a=\frac{v_(impact)+v_(rebound)}{Collision Time}$$

Comment: Thank you very much Tausif.  It seems that determining the coefficient of restitution is the tricky part.

Comment: You don't have to determine it as it's usually given in questions like this. You're welcome. Please verify the answer if you find it satisfactory.

Comment: In reality we can actually measure the coefficient of restitution by measuring the rebound heights.