# Calculating rebound force of an object

Tags: classical-mechanics, experimental-physics

There is already a question [similar to this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/339064/falling-object-rebound).
I am wondering if there is any way to calculate the rebound force if the **impact time is unknown**. Here are the knowns:

- mass of object
- height of drop
- height of rebound
- final velocity and initial velocity for rebound

I cannot find a way to actually record the impact time in a practical investigation and was wondering if this was enough data to find the rebound force

Comment: If you cannot get impact time, can you get impact distance or impact depth?  That can be used as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not have enough data to find the impact force. You know the change in momentum caused by the impact, which tells you the product of the impact time and the average impact force. But without an estimate of impact time you cannot estimate the average force.

You could have a very rigid object which creates a large impact force but over a very short time. Or you could have a soft but quite elastic object which deforms easily on impact and so creates a smaller impact force but over a longer time. Both objects could have the same coefficient of restitution, which is the ratio of speeds before and after impact.

Imagine cricket ball versus tennis ball.

Comment: I am nothing above year 11 level in physics so please excuse my ignorance. Is there anyway to correlate different bounce heights with a different force (instantaneous force as soon as the object leaves contact with the floor). I would have thought a higher force would correlate to a higher bounce height, or is there error in my thinking? Thakyou

Comment: @haynenewell Difference in successive bounce heights tells you the energy that has been lost in the bounce - but you already know this because you have the velocities immediately before and after the bounce. It is another way of measuring the coefficient of restitution - but you still can't distinguish between a large impact force acting for a short time and a lower impact force acting for a longer time.